# Ao abrir o Popover[bootstrap] a tela perde o foco e vai pro topo

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, framework, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma tela de consulta onde alimento uma tabela html com os registros do banco de dados. Em uma das colunas, de cada linha, há algumas opções como editar, excluir, add fotos e outra opção que abre o Popover.

Esse Popover é do Bootstrap 3 e tá acontecendo que toda vez que clico nestes botões do popover a tela perde o foco de onde está e vai pro topo da página, eu não quero que isso aconteça, como proceder?

Segue o código:

```
<td class="col-small center">
<div class="action-buttons">
    <div id="popover_content_AlugadoVendido" style="display: none">
        <form class="marcarComoVendido">
            <div>
                <p>
                    <input <%=checkNone%> type="radio" name="marcarComoVendido" id="none" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=none&idInput=none&outroInput=marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'none');" /> NENHUM
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input <%=checkVendido%> type="radio" name="marcarComoVendido" id="marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=vendido&idInput=marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> VENDIDO
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input <%=checkAlugado%> type="radio" name="marcarComoVendido" id="marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=alugado&idInput=marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> ALUGADO
                </p>                                
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="popoverAlugadoVendido" data-toggle="popover" data-rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-cog bigger-130"></i></a>
</td>
```

E aqui o javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popoverAlugadoVendido').popover({
        title: '<b>Alugado ou Vendido</b> <button class="close" data-toggle="clickover" data-dismiss="popover" aria-hidden="true" onclick="$(\'.popoverAlugadoVendido\').popover(\'hide\');">&times;</button>',
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'click',
        container: 'body',
        content: function() {
            return $('#popover_content_AlugadoVendido').html();
        },
        html: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi retirando a tag href do link.

```
<a class="popoverAlugadoVendido" data-toggle="popover" data-rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-cog bigger-130"></i></a>
```